# Not able to link CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create re-sizable tables in HTML. As, the data there will be of different length. But not able to link css and js code with HTML.
They are each in separate folder create in same directory.
I tried keeping them in same folder also, but not loading.
Chrome developers mode is also not showing any error, but still only 
If there is any other efficient way to have re-sizable table please do suggest.
Below js code.

```
$(function(){
  var thHeight = $("table#demo-table th:first").height();
  $("table#demo-table th").resizable({
      handles: "e",
      minHeight: thHeight,
      maxHeight: thHeight,
      minWidth: 40,
      resize: function (event, ui) {
        var sizerID = "#" + $(event.target).attr("id") + "-sizer";
        $(sizerID).width(ui.size.width);
      }
  });
});
```

Below is Css

```
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
table#demo-table th {
  background-color: #006;
  color: #fff;
}
table#demo-table th, 
table#demo-table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}
table.cellpadding-0 td {
    padding: 0;
}
table.cellspacing-0 {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.bordered th, 
table.bordered td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;
}
table.bordered th:last, 
table.bordered td:last {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Below is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/democss.css">
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/demojs.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="demo-table" class="bordered cellpadding-0 cellspacing-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id='column-header-1'>Column Header 1<div id='column-header-1-sizer'></div></th>
            <th id='column-header-2'>Column Header 2<div id='column-header-2-sizer'></div></th>
            <th id='column-header-3'>Column Header 3<div id='column-header-3-sizer'></div></th>
            <th id='column-header-4'>Column Header 4<div id='column-header-4-sizer'></div></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <td>My Data 1</td>
            <td>My Data 2</td>
            <td>My Data 3</td>
            <td>My Data 4</td>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the jQuery library and jQuery UI for the `.resizable()` method, aswell as the jQuery UI CSS support

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/demojs.js" ></script>
```

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Resizable TH</title>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
/* instead of style use <link> this is a demo.*/
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

table#demo-table th {
  background-color: #006;
  color: #fff;
}

table#demo-table th,
table#demo-table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

table.cellpadding-0 td {
  padding: 0;
}

table.cellspacing-0 {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.bordered th,
table.bordered td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;
}

table.bordered th:last,
table.bordered td:last {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="demo-table" class="bordered cellpadding-0 cellspacing-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id='column-header-1'>Column Header 1<div id='column-header-1-sizer'></div></th>
            <th id='column-header-2'>Column Header 2<div id='column-header-2-sizer'></div></th>
            <th id='column-header-3'>Column Header 3<div id='column-header-3-sizer'></div></th>
            <th id='column-header-4'>Column Header 4<div id='column-header-4-sizer'></div></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <td>My Data 1</td>
            <td>My Data 2</td>
            <td>My Data 3</td>
            <td>My Data 4</td>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
// Use <script> with src to your .js file. This is a demo.
jQuery(function($) {
  var thHeight = $("table#demo-table th:first").height();
  $("table#demo-table th").resizable({
    handles: "e",
    minHeight: thHeight,
    maxHeight: thHeight,
    minWidth: 40,
    resize: function(event, ui) {
      var sizerID = "#" + $(event.target).attr("id") + "-sizer";
      $(sizerID).width(ui.size.width);
    }
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```